# Using lambda for the first time. Looking to put more code inline if possible

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda

I'm currently trying to teach my self how to use lambda expressions (really like how they look)

On my win form I have 2 buttons which are used to browse directories, the user selected directory is then placed in a corresponding text box. This is what I have so far.

In the setDirectory event is there any way I can do the button check inline? I'm really looking to clean up the code in the setDirectory event.

```
        private void setDirectory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Button dirButton = sender as Button;
           TextBox dirTextBox;

           if (dirButton.Name == fromDirButton.Name)
               dirTextBox = fromTextBox;
           else
               dirTextBox = toTextBox;

           Func<string> setDirectory = SetDirectory();
           fromTextBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { dirTextBox.Text = setDirectory(); }));
        }

        private static Func<string> SetDirectory()
        {
           using (FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
           {
               folderBrowserDialog.Description = "Select Path";
               folderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
               folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
               return () => folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath != "" ? folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath : "";
           }
        }
```

Comment: This does not seem like a great use of lambda functionality. Why not just use a conventional method?

Comment: As above, this should just be in a single regular method

Comment: Just trying to learn how to use lambda to be honest. This is purely educational

Comment: @AceK47 If you want to learn how to use a particular feature, you should be using it for problems that that tool is designed to solve.  Trying to use it for problems it's not designed to solve will just teach you how to use it incorrectly, not how to use it appropriately.

Comment: Your usage of lambda expression in `SetDirectory` is incorrect: it captures a disposed object.

Comment: You're asking how to put "more" code inline, but your extra use of lambda so far hasn't actually helped you inline code any more than it would have been. `SetDirectory` could have returned the string and you could have called it directly, inline (in fact it would have saved you from writing the additional line `setDirectory = SetDirectory()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Looking to put more code inline if possible**

Why? This does not look like a proper use of [**Lambda Expressions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb397687.aspx).

Your question should be:

**When to use Lambda Expressions, and when not to?**

**Lambda Expressions** don't replace conventional coding such as dialogs, etc. They provide a way to express in a more functional way of what is being done.

```
var net30PastDueInvoices = 
    invoiceRepository.GetInvoicesFor(currentClient)
        .Where(f => 30 < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-f.InvoiceDate));
```

Or even to process into an iteration:

```
var items = repository.GetList().ForEach(i => {
        // Process items here.
        // Notice that the code processed here is located in a foreach loop
        // especially for the given purpose within an anonymous method.
        // Should you need to perform this operation over and over again,
        // you should extract this to a proper method and describe what it 
        // does in its name.
    });
```

The way you're trying to use Lambda Expressions is very discouraged as it only increase code complexity.

In short, **Lambda Expression** are very practical to express business rules and the like in a functional way. Other than that, [**Keep It Simple, Stupid (KISS)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!

> ***Disclaimer***

I'm not saying you're stupid, here. Follow the link to know more.

Comment: Yeah, basically what I was implying.  Good answer-

Answer (score 1):

Your usage isn't truly ideal for a Lambda, Lambda's truly hit their stride within *Linq & Generics* which make it remarkably easy to use.  An example:

```
List<string> collection = new List<string>();
if(!collection.Any())
     // Collection isn't null.

var quantity = collection.Count(c => c > 5);
```

As you can see the Lambda pipes the data, which makes sense.  It becomes expressive, rather than obfuscated.

**The area in which you could potentially use Lambda's, may be better off with a more traditional implementation.  Simply because it is becoming more complex and less expressive.  Which makes the code harder to maintain and refactor, simplicity is often the best approach.**

*I recommend trying to learn the Lambda in the proper environment, not for the sake of using them.*